# Firestore security rules and environment variables

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

It is possible to define environment specific variables for Firestore Security rules? Just like it is possible for [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible out of the box as of now (Jan 6th 2023). I had to write a custom webpack plugin for this purpose.

Comment: Is that plug-in publicly available? A link to it would be helpful.

Comment: Not publicly available, sorry, my coding is too bad for making it public! But I can give you some directions via private message if you want